# config.action_view.debug_rjs will be removed in 3.1, from 3.1 onwards you will need to install prototype-rails to continue to use RJS templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting a warning.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: config.action_view.debug_rjs will be removed in 3.1, from 3.1 onwards you will need to install prototype-rails to continue to use RJS templates . (called from <top (required)> at /Users/me/projects/my_app/config/environment.rb:5)
```

Can anybody tel me how to solve this. I am not using prototype I am using standard jquery js file with jquery.rails.js instead of gem.

```
rails -v
  Rails 3.0.10
ruby -v
   ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]
rvm -v
  rvm 1.8.0 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning is being caused by your config file. Look for a line like `config.action_view.debug_rjs = true` in `{app_root}/config/environments/development.rb` or `production.rb` and comment it out. If you're not using rjs views anyway then you won't miss the debugging in development mode anyway (and it's off by default in production)